# Identify specific row based on Date

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What this code does is to identify the row of the array based on the input (Date) and return the values associated with the input date.

However, this for loop is not working as it does not respect the if condition and always returns the last row of the array.

```
function viewData() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Overall Cashflow"); //Data entry Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cashflow Tracker Data"); //Data Sheet
  var data = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var date = formSS.getRange("H5").getDisplayValue();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
        if (data[i][0] == date) {
           break; 
        }
        var oldinflow = data[i][1];
        var oldoutflow = data[i][2]; 
  }
  

  formSS.getRange("H8").setValue(oldinflow);
  formSS.getRange("H11").setValue(oldoutflow);
}
```

Comment: For a better answer please add some data sample and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: Tan Wei Ming could you please try my updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the **valueOf()** of the date object instead.

Try this:

```
function viewData() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Overall Cashflow"); //Data entry Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cashflow Tracker Data"); //Data Sheet
  var data = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var date = formSS.getRange("H5").getValue().valueOf();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
        if (data[i][0].valueOf() == date) {
           break; 
        }
        var oldinflow = data[i][1];
        var oldoutflow = data[i][2]; 
  }
  

  formSS.getRange("H8").setValue(oldinflow);
  formSS.getRange("H11").setValue(oldoutflow);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: `==` will test two object's addresses in memory.  When you retrieve one value via `.getValue()` and the "same" value via `.getValues()`, the resulting memory locations will compare false.  To use `==` with Date objects, you have to say `range.getValue().valueOf() == bigRange.getValues()[i][j].valueOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

`getValues()` might return Date object for cells holding "dates", by the other hand `getDisplayValue()` will return  a string. This might explain why `(data[i][0] == date` is no working.

To prevent on *quick and dirty* solution that might be good enough is instead of using `getValues()`, to use `getDisplayValues()`.